# Delete from one table in my database(SQL server) is slow

Tags: sql-server

I have one table that have two trigger for insert and update.The record number is 700000 and delete from table is slow,can this problem for  triggers that is for insert and after update?

My Trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FillFinallAmount_UpdateTR] ON [dbo].[StuffPriceInfo] 
after Update AS 
--declare var
    select @fatherid=i.FatherPriceInfoId from inserted i; 
    select @priceid=i.PriceInfoId from inserted i; 
    select @stuffcodeseq=i.stuffcodeseq from inserted i; 
    select @StuffServiceCode=i.StuffServiceCode from inserted i; 
    select @PriceType=i.PriceType from inserted i; 
    select @TaskType=i.TaskType from inserted i; 
    select @basepercent=i.basepercent from inserted i; 
    select @NewAmount=i.NewAmount from inserted i; 
    select @FinalAmount=i.FinalAmount from inserted i; 
    select @dbasepercent=i.basepercent from deleted i; 
    select @dNewAmount=i.NewAmount from deleted i; 
    select @dFinalAmount=i.FinalAmount from deleted i; 
    select @dfatherid=i.FatherPriceInfoId from deleted i; 
    IF(@dbasepercent!=@basepercent or @dNewAmount!=@NewAmount or @dFinalAmount!=@FinalAmount or @dfatherid!=@fatherid) 
    BEGIN 
        IF update(FatherPriceInfoId) 
        BEGIN 
            IF @fatherid is not null 
            BEGIN 
                set @fatheramount=(select FinalAmount from StuffPriceInfo where PriceInfoId=@fatherid) 
                set @FinalAmount=((@fatheramount*@basepercent*0.01)+@NewAmount) 
                update StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=@FinalAmount where PriceInfoId=@priceid 
                update StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=((@FinalAmount*basepercent*0.01)+NewAmount)   where FatherPriceInfoId=@priceid 
            END 
            else 
            begin 
                update StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=@NewAmount where PriceInfoId=@priceid 
                update StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=((@NewAmount*basepercent*0.01)+NewAmount)   where FatherPriceInfoId=@priceid 
            END 
        END 
        ELSE if update(basepercent) 
        BEGIN 
            IF @fatherid is not null 
            BEGIN 
                SET @fatheramount=(select FinalAmount from StuffPriceInfo where PriceInfoId=@fatherid) 
                SET @FinalAmount=((@fatheramount*@basepercent*0.01)+@NewAmount) 
                UPDATE StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=@FinalAmount where PriceInfoId=@priceid 
                UPDATE StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=((@FinalAmount*basepercent*0.01)+NewAmount)   where FatherPriceInfoId=@priceid 
            END 
            ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                UPDATE StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=@NewAmount where PriceInfoId=@priceid 
                UPDATE StuffPriceInfo set FinalAmount=((@NewAmount*basepercent*0.01)+NewAmount)   where FatherPriceInfoId=@priceid 
            END 
        END 

AND .....
```

Comment: What is the DDL for the triggers? We don't have enough information here

Comment: Can you add more information please?

Comment: Considering you have `and .......` at the end of that trigger that isn't the whole thing. I suspect that your trigger is, well, very big. I suspect this is only *part* of the problem.

Comment: A couple of problems with the trigger though, firstly, it assumes that only 1 row will be updated at a time, it shouldn't. You can update multiple rows at a time. Also, you can assign multiple variables at the time: For example `SELECT @fatherid=i.FatherPriceInfoId, @priceid=i.PriceInfoId FROM inserted i;` However, that method isn't what you want to use anyway, as that (again) assumes that `inserted` contains **only** one row.

Comment: Honestly, this problem is going to be very difficult to solve without the full trigger. The root cause, however, is that you appear to be thinking very programmatically with your trigger. Instead of thinking of the data you need to `UPDATE`, you're thinking of each row and column you need to `UPDATE` and doing each one on it's own. SQL Server's forté is working in sets. Your trigger is fundamentally flawed (accepts only 1 row), but it's going to (probably) be a lot to get it working correctly, and well; something that can't be achieved without the full trigger, and sample and expected results.

Comment: You complain about delete performance but you post code of an update trigger? How are these related?

Comment: I have not trigger for delete. but delete commands is slow. my question is whether update trigger can fire when delete command execute?

Comment: @Amir - the answer to that question is no - a delete statement for table x will not cause an update trigger for table x to execute. However, I suggest you verify that the table has no delete trigger and that it is not a part of any indexed view. Deleting 700k rows will take some time. If the table is in use, then you must also considering other connections blocking your delete statement.

Comment: I disabled insert and update trigger and run delete query, but the problem do not resolved!  at next test I delete the relation between two column of table  'PriceInfoId' and 'FatherPriceInfoId', after that the delete run in normal time.  
The deleted relation is necessary and must create again,does anyone have a solution for new problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem resolve by create index for 'FatherPriceInfoId' column that has relation with 'PriceInfoId' column (both columns are in same table and 'PriceInfoId' is primary key)